# Create objects with names from an elements id attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a few objects whose names are the id attributes of the divs with `class="characteristic"`. How do i get the id for the name?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var characteristicElements = document.getElementsByClassName("characteristic");
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < characteristicElements.length ; i++ ) {
        var characteristicElements[i].getAttribute("id") = { set: false, val: 0, unn: 0 };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a map then, using an object, and use the ID as property name:

```
var objects = {};

var characteristicElements = document.getElementsByClassName("characteristic");
for ( var i = 0 ; i < characteristicElements.length ; i++ ) {
    objects[characteristicElements[i].id] = {'set': false, val: 0, unn: 0 };
}
```

Afaik you have to put `set` in quotes because it is a keyword in object literals. I could be wrong though. Also note that `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE8 and before.

I recommend reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) - [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 2):

`characteristicElements[i].getAttribute("id")` is a string. What you're doing is like `var "foo" = "bar";`, doesn't make sense. What you want to do is doable but only with eval, and eval is evil. If you put the objects within another object it gets much easier:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var characteristicElements = document.getElementsByClassName("characteristic");
    var objects = {}; // New empty object
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < characteristicElements.length ; i++ ) {
        objects[characteristicElements[i].getAttribute("id")] = { set: false, val: 0, unn: 0 };
    }
};
```

objects["foo"] is the same as objects.foo, just another notation.